# How do I fix a file that crashes Numbers?

Tags: crash, numbers

A long time ago, I made a relatively simple Numbers document with some tables containing text and images. It lives in iCloud, and I can preview it using Quick Look.

But now when I try to open it, Numbers crashes, 100% of the time. Here's the [crash log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jtbandes/013e1bf1087050af0330857ae3d6b9f5/raw/5bdb156269a82921ba508e45cf08f5fb86359217/Numbers%2520crash%2520log).

The file is only 1.4MB in size; its filename contains only ASCII characters; nothing else seems out of the ordinary. Another Numbers document, right alongside it in iCloud, opens just fine. The crash happens no matter whether I open it from Finder or the Numbers Open dialog.

What can I try in order to fix the file or work around the crash? (Unfortunately I'd rather not share the file here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by opening the file in Numbers for iOS (synced via iCloud) and making some modifications. The updated version then opened correctly on my Mac.

Comment: Great idea! They must have differing implementations on iOS/OS X, which was a win for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to report a bug in Apple Numbers using this form:

http://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html

Be sure to include the exact version of Numbers you're running as well as the complete crash log, or at least this part of the stack trace:

```
  Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010e4ccbca 0x10d523000 + 16423882
1   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010e3e11ab 0x10d523000 + 15458731
2   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010e3e1061 0x10d523000 + 15458401
3   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010e3ca64c 0x10d523000 + 15365708
4   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010dd6a9c7 0x10d523000 + 8681927
5   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010e3ca5bc 0x10d523000 + 15365564
6   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010dc0124d 0x10d523000 + 7201357
7   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010dbebd2b 0x10d523000 + 7114027
8   com.apple.iWork.Numbers         0x000000010d5327ec 0x10d523000 + 63468
```

Apple will have the debug symbols that tells them, which specific functions are involved in the crash.

Then you have to sit tight and wait until a new version of Numbers comes out where the bug is hopefully fixed. It is entirely likely that the bug won't be fixed, so don't get your hopes up too high.

Fixing the file yourself requires intimate knowledge of the Numbers file format, as it sounds like you might have a valid file that crashes Numbers - and not a corrupted file. It is very hard to give advice on how to fix the file yourself when you're not sharing the file in question.